How to generate metadata info with openapi-generator
In my openapi.yaml file there are some information I would like to access in my code.
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  title: Title
  description: My description
  version: "1.0"

Now I would like to be able to access the version information contained in the api-specification. Is there a way to tell the generator to generate these metadata?
I am using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin with the spring generator.

Do you mean you want to access application version in openapi.yml file? Please clarify because your question is not clear

I would like the generater to generate a class which contains the information from my info block of the openapi.yaml

which plugin you're using for yml to POJO conversion? If possible please include in your question

Hopefully this will helpful. I'm using this plugin to get the MetaData information, this will generate configuration class
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>openapi-generator</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals><!---->
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/petstore.yml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.openapigenerator.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.openapigenerator.model</modelPackage>
                            <configOptions>
                                <GenerateOpenAPIMetadata>true</GenerateOpenAPIMetadata>
                            </configOptions>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

Basically this config helping to get this information
<configOptions>                            
      <GenerateOpenAPIMetadata>true</GenerateOpenAPIMetadata>
</configOptions>



Thats it. It seems to be an undocumented feature (at least I could not finde anything). This flag ist ignored if one uses the supportingFilesToGenerate feature. But  SpringDocConfiguration.java can be added to this block. Additinally the Swagger Models dependancy needs to be added.
